# How can you calculate the URL link for a YouTube video RAW on Google Video with this script?

Tags: javascript, youtube, tampermonkey

Sorry if the title is a bit misleading but,

I wanted to download some music from YouTube just now, and I ran this tampermonkey [script.](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5566-youtube-links/code)

Yes, it works well, and doesn't just redirect you to some random site, but I actually want to know how it calculates the URL to go to (something like xyz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?/../../ etc). It's just a simple javascript script, but I'm having a hard time understanding it. All I'm asking is for someone to help me simplify this script and tell me how it generates this URL. I've done a bit of close examination and this is what I have so far:

It has multiple options for the video/audio download

Each type has it's own little part in the generated URL; one example is:

```
  var resList = [
    { res: 3160, q : "ultrahighres" },
    { res: 1536, q : "highres" },
    { res: 1080, q: "hd1080" },
    { res: 720, q : "hd720" },
    { res: 480, q : "large" },
    { res: 360, q : "medium" }
    ];
```

I see a lot of data.match with random strings that look like something that would go after the googlevideo.com/videoplayback?/ thing

Thats all I understand from this. I tried my hardest to figure this out so theres that, feel free to edit this if you think something should be changed or I made an error.

Thanks!

Comment: All such scripts/utilities parse `formats` or `adaptiveFormats` of the video page config. To get this data they either download the entire video URL and parse the html response (that script does this and it's rather baaad) or use an official YouTube API (requires a personal API key) or use the get_video_info service used by YouTube itself (example: parseVideoInfo in [FYTE](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/9252/code)).

Comment: Hmmm... Is there any documentation for using the get_video_info service?

Comment: No, it's an internal undocumented thing but it's rather trivial to use as you'll see after inspecting the response and the code of other scripts.